# What does Don Corleone Sr. mean when he says,"...all the 'comedy' you're playing with that young girl?"

Tags: dialogue, the-godfather

In *The Godfather*, Don Vito Corleone is mad with Santino about talking out of turn while he is having a conversation with Sollozo about not wanting to bankroll ("finance") their drug business. Vito says to Santino, "What's the matter with you? I think your brain is going soft from all the comedy you're playing with that young girl. Never tell anyone outside the Family what you are thinking again."

Comment: I suggest that its from thinking he has a chance with the young girl.  But this is just a theory and not enough for me to post an answer...

Comment: I wonder if you are asking about the exact word "comedy?" If you are, he means "fooling around" or some other phrase to describe irresponsible behavior. It is perhaps a small reminder that not only if Vito not a native speaker of English but in fact spoke Italian/Sicilian as an adult. That is a nice choice on the part of the writer -- somehow it feels very natural to have Vito speak slightly unidiomatic English.

Answer (score 3):

[Santino was having affairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonny_Corleone):

> He also has several mistresses, including his sister Connie's friend Lucy Mancini.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure it was a comment regarding the affair he was having with the bridesmaid from his sister's wedding that he was having an affair with. I've always assumed she was the mother of Vincent, Andy Garcia's character in The Godfather 3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Vincent's last name is Mancini (which he changes I think to Coreleone) and the bridesmaid is Lucy Mancini who IIRC has quite a few pages devoted to her in the book -- whether she has the kid in the book (since Sonny is killed, Vincent had to have been born near the time of the other events of the film) I do not recall.